# Object models in flux / redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, flux

So i am learning the flux pattern using redux as a framework for it, to generate a mobile application in react-native (no backend).I feel I have been fighting against the pattern for some time due I come from an OO background and was expecting my model to be abstracted and bind somewhere in the pattern.

Last night I think I had an epiphany by thinking that this pattern enforces the idea that all is data and how is treated in reaction to events. So is fully functional programming and no abstractions (that have state) have a place inside this pattern.

So just to map to an OO world I have explain it in this mode to my brain:

- `internal objects in the store`: each is equivalent to the properties of a class.
- `Event`: equivalent to the reaction to something that happen and calls methods from a class.
- `reducer`: the methods that transform the data inside a class.
- `views`: the representation to the user of those abstractions.

My questions then are:

1. Is this weird theory (models inside the store). valid or just a bad idea?
2. if not valid, where do my models hook in a redux based application?
3. if not valid, this means this pattern is just to use on the front-end?

Comment: Indeed it can be hard to let go of old paradigms, but I think you're better off thinking about a redux application as just an object store, which has a subscription function in case you want to be notified anytime the object store changes. Forget about models for now. And while there's nothing saying redux is primarily for the front-end, usually back end applications don't have persistent state in memory, but that depends I guess. Any application that stores dynamic state in memory could potentially benefit from used a tool like redux

Comment: thanks for the answer @azium, I agree at some points i was feeling getting crazy just by not letting go of OO :)

Comment: @azium do you want to put that as answer? i will mark it as valid answer